# How to download multiple FTP files in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ftp, wget

I need to download around 200 FTP files from NCBI website.

I have a linux sytem which throws an error "Connection timed out" while using **wget**. I think this error would be due to administrative privileges.

So, I am have switched to Windows7. Could anyone suggest me a way to download all the FTPs in a go?

Answer (score 1):

Wget is for downloading web pages, do you mean mget?  If you're getting Connection Timed out I wouldn't think that would be due to permissions.

mget should work in the Windows 7 built-in command line FTP client or you could try using a client like WinSCP, this has a GUI so you can select a bunch of files and drag to download.

Comment: `wget` works with FTP protocol just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You said Windows 7. Well, Windows PowerShell 3.0 and later comes with a built-in `Invoke-WebRequest` command, whose shortcut is ... surprise, surprise... `wget`. So, you have native `wget` in Windows 7.

Your first problem is that Windows 7 comes with PowerShell 2.0, not 3.0. But you can get Windows PowerShell 5.1 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

You can also download GNU WGet for Windows from: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Download-Managers/GNU-Wget.shtml